# "NAs introduced by coercion": warning with data.table::fifelse - but no NA in output

Tags: r, data.table

I am confused by the following warning when updating a column by reference with `fifelse`.

> Warning in fifelse(char == "PL", 2, as.numeric(char)): NAs introduced by coercion

But there are no `NA`!!

`str(mydt)` shows that the class conversion to numeric has worked.

Can someone explain?

```r
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(char = c('1','PL'))
mydt[, newcol := fifelse(char == 'PL', 2, as.numeric(char))]
#> Warning in fifelse(char == "PL", 2, as.numeric(char)): NAs introduced by
#> coercion
mydt
#>    char newcol
#> 1:    1      1
#> 2:   PL      2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```
devtools::session_info()
    #>  data.table  * 1.12.6  2019-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `fifelse` as it is a property of `as.numeric` when applied to elements that are non-numeric i.e. when do `as.numeric(char)`, the non-numeric element is coerced to `NA`

```
as.numeric(c("1", "PL"))
#[1]  1 NA
```

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

According to `?fifelse`, usage is

> fifelse(test, yes, no, na=NA)

and

> yes, no - Values to return depending on TRUE/FALSE element of test. They must be the same type and be either length 1 or the same length of test.

So, the `as.numeric` is called as 'no' argument on the whole column and it ensures that it changes on the whole column and not on a part of it

---

If we don't want the warning, wrap the `as.numeric` on the outside of `fifelse` or use `replace`

```
mydt[, newcol := as.numeric(replace(char, grepl('\\D', char), 2))]
```

Or

```
mydt[, newcol := as.numeric(fifelse(char == 'PL', '2', char))]
```

`fifelse` is type specific, so, if we are specific a different type for 'yes', 'no', it would complain.  The option is to use 'yes' with a character '2' and then apply `as.numeric` on the output of `fifelse`

Comment: I am aware of that. but It doesn't make sense to me - the ifelse statement should ensure that as.numeric() is only called on vector elements that can be transformed to numeric

Comment: @Tjebo You are calling the `as.numeric` on the whole column and not on part

Comment: that is interesting. So this *has* to do with how fifelse works.

Comment: @Tjebo It is the same implementation as `ifelse`, but more optimized

Comment: Hah, I think you may possibly remember a similar question of mine a few weeks ago. Oh dear. Is there a better approach in this case?

Comment: @Tjebo I added some modiffications